# Firebreath project changes are not displayed

Tags: c++, firebreath

I installed firebreath in Mac os x. Also, I installed the plugin. My problem is that when I try to do some change in my project (OpenOnDesktopPluginAPI.cpp), the changes are not refreshed in my browser. For example, I modified this method:

```
std::string OpenOnDesktopPluginAPI::get_version()
{
    //return "CURRENT_VERSION";
    return "MY_VERSION";
}
```

If I execute "plugin().version" in my browser console, it supposed to show me "MY_VERSION", but it shows me "CURRENT_VERSION" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you:

1. Recompile the browser plugin?
2. Restart the browser (if you replace the plugin binary while the browser is running it won't reload it)
3. Reinstall the plugin (if you copied the plugin to Internet Plugins/ then you need to copy the new version; if you used a symlink this won't matter)

Comment: Hi, I solved my problem. I reinstalled my plugin and it worked :) thanks a lot! The symlink did not work for me, so I created a copy of the original. The browsers don´t recognize the symlink as a plugin :S

Comment: I have used symlinks, so I promise they can work; I don't know why yours didn't specifically.  If thats the answer, please mark it as the answer =]